# Did Anakin want kids?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, anakin-skywalker

We can gather from [Attack of the Clones](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) that Padme wanted kids:

> PADMÉ: Popular rule is not democracy, Ani. It gives the
> people what they want, not what they need. And, truthfully,
> I was relieved when my two terms were up. So were my
> parents. They worried about me during the blockade and
> couldn't wait for it all to be over. Actually, **I was hoping
> to have a family by now**... My sisters have the **most
> amazing, wonderful kids**... So when the Queen asked me to
> serve as Senator, I couldn't refuse her.

And from [Revenge of the Sith](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html), Anakin appears supportive of the pregnancy--even though it could get him kicked out of the Order--but doesn't go into whether or not he wanted it before:

> PADME: Anakin, this baby will change our lives. I doubt the Queen will continue to allow me to serve in the Senate, and **if the Council discovers you are the father, you will be expelled from the Jedi Order**.
>
> ANAKIN: **I know** ….
> ...
> ANAKIN: He's been a father to me, but he's still on the Council. Don't tell [Obi-wan] anything!
>
> PADME: I won't, Anakin.
>
> ANAKIN: I don't need his help . . . **Our baby is a blessing**, not a problem.
> ...
> ANAKIN: I won't be a pawn in your political game. **The Jedi are my family.**

We also know that he has familial issues since his mom was killed, but that extent is never explained in the films.

**Is there anything that talks about Anakin's desire to have a family before the events of ROTS?**

Comment: I expect birth control devices to exist in galaxy far far away. I am sure Anakin could have used it if he really didn't want kids.

Comment: "*Anakin felt his mouth drop open. Of all the things it could have been, he hadn’t expected this. A baby? We’re going to have a baby?*" (Junior novel) - Like most teenagers that get their girlfriends pregnant, he doesn't seem to have given it much thought either way.

Comment: @ILoveYou I don't think the use or non-use of contraceptives is a good enough indicator of someone's desire to want a family

Comment: @Valorum But weren't they married when they conceived?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Oh well, I suppose.

Comment: Well, there's always the theory that [they weren't Anakin's kids](http://uproxx.com/hitfix/one-simple-trick-that-makes-that-star-wars-prequels-way-more-watchable/)...

Comment: It is good enough indicator for a married adult. Also, remember, the technology was so advanced in the galaxy far far away that I doubt any device of birth control would have failed. Condoms with nanites which would terminate sperms upon leakage...

Comment: @ILoveYou Even if that's true, it still doesn't answer the question of whether or not he talked about it beforehand

Comment: @Machavity Wow. Fan theories for the win.

Comment: A galaxy far, far away also probably has different consequences for parenthood. Even if Anakin's expelled from the Jedi order, he isn't likely to be functioning off minimum wage for basic necessities like diapers, or personally dealing with dirty diapers and lack of sleep when there's droids to handle that.

Comment: @IAMGROOT, a sperm could 'use the force' to bypass them ;-)

Comment: @TimSparrow It'd be hard for them to subtly wave their tail though

Comment: @TimSparrow +1. I never thought about it. A force-sensitive sperm can definitely smash nanites. I am thinking about writing a fanfic showing sperm vs nanite. The name can be "Microscopic Hope of the Jedi" or something like that. Also, it'd also explain how there are so many force sensitives in the galaxy if Jedis don't marry. Obviously, the masturbated out sperms fly (using force) out to impregnate random girls across the galaxy. It'd also explain Anakin's virgin birth.

Comment: @IAMGROOT Share the link once you're done, please

Answer (score 3):

Yes, he wanted kids because he openly showed happiness when Padme reveled she was pregnant.

> Padmé Amidala: Something wonderful has happened. Ani, I'm pregnant.
>
> Anakin Skywalker: That's... That's wonderful.
>
> Padmé Amidala: What are we gonna do?
>
> Anakin Skywalker: We're not gonna worry about anything right now. All right? This is a happy moment. The happiest moment of my life. 
> <sub>Star Wars: Episode III – Revenge of the Sith (2005)</sub>

[image: Anikan and Padme happy about kids]

Comment: I guess it could be assumed that if he *didn't* want kids prior, he would've reacted negatively

Answer (score -4):

Let's do some amateurish psychological profiling :P

**Anakin**:  Born in harsh environment as a slave-boy, never had a father, taken from his mother very young, basically an orphan. Introduced to Jedi Order who looked at him as some kind of prodigy, becomes essentially child-solider put in mortal danger all the time. Subconsciously looking for home, for a father and mother figure. His teacher Obi-Wan is too young and unwilling to become said father-figure, he is more of older brother ("You were my brother, Anakin") , somewhat unhealthy rivalry develops between them. Steps in Palpatine, and rest is history. As for mother figure, Anakin falls for significantly older and more mature girl (Oedipus complex anyone :P ) . He wants to protect her, but often lets her steer him in life, something mother should do.

**Padme**: Promoted beyond her ability. Considers herself as part of "enlightened elite" (*Popular rule is not democracy, Annie. It gives the people what they want, not what they need.*) with duty to rule. Also, considers herself smart, although her cognitive abilities are average, and she is unwilling but useful pawn in Palpatine's game. Yet, she is far more cunning than Anakin. She is attracted to him because he undoubtedly has power, yet remains naive little boy in his heart, someone she could control and manipulate, therefore building her own self-esteem .

**Therefore, does Anakin want children ?** Anakin is undoubtedly less experienced in sexual matters then Padme, she is his first real girlfriend, while on other hand Padme had other boyfriends (we know of two : [Palo Jemabie](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palo_Jemabie) and [Rush Clovis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rush_Clovis)). Considering, as shown above, that she controlled their relationship, it is almost sure that she controlled question of contraception. Therefore, it was her decision to conceive a child, maybe as a sort of insurance to keep Anakin close to her. Anakin was put before *fait accompli*, he was confused but then accepted the fact. He let things slide as usual in their marriage, Padme making important decisions for both of them . Therefore, answer to our question would be that he probably didn't consciously want to have kids right now, be he was not against that idea either. He just accepted matter at hands.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. Can you offer any evidence to justify this pop-psychology? :-)

Comment: @Valorum What more evidence do you need ? :P Anakin being classic case orphan without family, desperately searching for one ? Or Padme promoted to level of incompetence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle), desperately trying to prove herself to others as serious politician instead of immature figurehead ?

Comment: Ignoring the snark about Padmé being incompetent, some *actual* evidence would include a book quote, a screenplay quote, an interview, etc etc

Comment: I assume everyone watched movies and knows Anakin's biography . One quote proving Padmes's belief that she knows better then people she represents what they need is included . References that Anakin is not her first serious relationship are also included .